# Search a line in text file and write a word before it

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to parse a text file search for functions and add `i` to that line. My input file is a text file where the data is column format. I read this text file search for all functions with arguments and add an extra column which has `i` written to every row that has the functions with arguments and `v` written to every row that has functions without arguments. The logic I used is

```
filter_list = ["int","unsigned","void","*"]
for line in f:
    if ".text" in line:
         if "()" in line:
            columns = line.split("  ")
            columns.insert(0, "v")
            g.write("  ".join(columns)+"  ")
            continue

         if "(" in line:
            for word in filter_list:
                columns = line.split()
                columns.insert(0, "i")
                g.write("  ".join(columns)+"  ")




f.close()
g.close()
```

This does not give the right output. This logic keeps on adding `i` to complete row after the first argument like

```
i  00010518  .text  hl_mount_storage(FileSystemObject&,  char  i  00010518  .text  hl_mount_storage(FileSystemObject&,  char  i  00010518  .text  hl_mount_storage(FileSystemObject&,  char  i  00010518  .text  hl_mount_storage(FileSystemObject&,  char  a  2007c000  .data  g_pkt_hist_wptr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line repeats the `g.write` to the output file for each of the words in your filter:

```
for word in filter_list:
```

so currently, 4 times (the length of `filter_list`). If you add another word, you'd get *5* copies of the same line.

Since you don't use `word` or `filter_list` anyway, just remove the entire `for` loop:

```
if "(" in line:
    columns = line.split()
    columns.insert(0, "i")
    g.write("  ".join(columns)+"  ")
```